# Word 2007 VBA: Need to return a custom document property as a string within VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint-2010, ms-word

As part of a SharePoint workflow, a custom document property named "Link to Graphic As Text" is filled in with a link to a graphic provided by the user. I'm trying to code a macro within the Word document template so that when the user runs it, the picture is added to the document. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Dim wdDoc As Document
Dim filePath As String

Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument

filePath = wdDoc.CustomDocumentProperties("Link to Graphics As Text").Value //receive error here

wdDoc.Shapes.AddPicture _
FileName:=filePath, _
LinkToFile:=msoTrue, _
SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
Left:=-5, _
Top:=5
```

Comment: what error number you have?

Comment: Run-Time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: it seems that there is not such a property you try to take value from? have you check if it exists with a loop or in other way?

Comment: I have not tried this, is there a method to return all doc properties?

Comment: see the code to check it in answer- too long to put it in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in my opinion there is not a property you want to take value of. Check if property exists in this way- by checking all properties and write them into Immediate window in IDE.

```
Sub Check_if_exists()

    Dim CDP As DocumentProperty
    For Each CDP In ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties
        Debug.Print CDP.Name, CDP.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You are correct, it is not a custom document property, it is a server propety. Is there any way to access this within VBA?

Comment: Server property? iI think it's possible but I have no experiences to help you in that area. You could possibly ask another question.

Comment: Turns out it was a ContentTypeProperty. You're answer lead me to find this, thanks a lot!